# Sequential requests using python-requests

Tags: python, for-loop, timeout, request, sequential

right now I'm using Flask, and I'm having trouble while trying to do more than one GET request using python requests module.

If I try to send a series of requests, the first one is completed successfully, but the other ones throw a timeout exception.

Here is part of the view's code:

```
import requests

sess = requests.Session()
site_url = 'http://www.example.com/api/'
steps = ['first_step', 'second_step', 'third_step']
step_responses = dict()
for s in steps:
    try:
        req = sess.get(site_url + s, timeout=5))
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        return jsonify({'result':False, 'error':'timeout'})
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return jsonify({'result':False, 'error':'connection_error'})
else:
        step_responses[s] = True
```

If I extract this part into a standalone .py file, it completes successfully.

```
import requests

sess = requests.Session()
site_url = 'http://www.example.com/api/'
steps = ['first_step', 'second_step', 'third_step']
step_responses = dict()
for s in steps:
    try:
        req = sess.get(site_url + s, timeout=5)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        step_responses[s] = 'timeout'
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        step_responses[s] = 'conn_error'
    else:
        step_responses[s] = 'ok'
print step_responses
```

Comment: Why the elaborate use of internal objects? Why not use `sess.get(site_url + s)` here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried but same result: second and third steps throw timeout exception.

Comment: I didn't say it was an answer, just an observation about how you are using the API. I don't see anything in your Python code that is causing timeouts. The server is doing it all by itself, it appears.

Comment: there is extraneous paren in the 1st code example

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. You may want to check the second and third steps

```
import requests

sess = requests.Session()
def module():
site_url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
steps = ['users', 'questions', 'tags']
step_responses = dict()
for s in steps:
    try:
        req = sess.get(site_url + s, timeout=5)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        return jsonify({'result':False, 'error':'timeout'})
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return jsonify({'result':False, 'error':'connection_error'})
else:
        step_responses[s] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure that you read all the values from the req object. 
I think you might need req.text and req.status_code or req.content

Check half-way down the page here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#request-sessions where they discuss session parameters
"class requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=10, pool_maxsize=10, max_retries=0, pool_block=False)"

I'm not at all sure how to use connection pools and so forth but the docs do say (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) (Look for Keep Alive)

"Note that connections are only released back to the pool for reuse once all body data has been read; be sure to either set stream to False or read the content property of the Response object."